# Hide New Document Command from ribbon using PowerShell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, ribbon

Want to know how to hide `New Document` command from ribbon using PowerShell in SP 2013.

Below is my code that does not work.

```
$CustomAction = $list.UserCustomActions.Add()
$CustomAction.Title = "Hide New Document"
$CustomAction.Location = "CommandUI.Ribbon"
$CustomAction.commandUIExtension = "
     <CommandUIExtension> 
         <CommandUIDefinitions> 
             <CommandUIDefinition Location='Ribbon.Library.Actions.NewDocument' /> 
         </CommandUIDefinitions>
     </CommandUIExtension>" 
$CustomAction.Update()
```

Comment: For hiding, you shoud use a `HideCustomAction` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms414790.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified a wrong Id. Use `Ribbon.Documents.New.NewDocument` instead of `Ribbon.Library.Actions.NewDocument`. Your code should look like this:

```
$CustomAction = $list.UserCustomActions.Add()
$CustomAction.Title = "Hide New Document"
$CustomAction.Location = "CommandUI.Ribbon"
$CustomAction.commandUIExtension = "
     <CommandUIExtension> 
         <CommandUIDefinitions> 
             <CommandUIDefinition Location='Ribbon.Documents.New.NewDocument' /> 
         </CommandUIDefinitions>
     </CommandUIExtension>" 
$CustomAction.Update()
```

You can find the full list of locations here: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML\CMDUI.xml

Comment: Hello Paul.your code worked!Thanks very much.One question I have, now  its hidden,how to go back to show this again?

Comment: Remove the custom action.

Comment: API for the same?

Comment: Usercustomactions.remove(mycustomavtipntitle);   ?

Comment: There is no Remove() method. You need to remove the custom action from the collection this way: $list.UserCustomActions[action.Id].Delete();
$list.Update();

Comment: so the action is captured or accessed through the title? like $allCustomActions = $list.UserCustomActions;  foreach($singleaction in  $allCustomActions) {  if($singleaction.Title -eq "Hide New Document")  {  $list.UserCustomActions[$singleaction.Id].Delete(); $list.Update(); } }

Comment: No. There is a property called "Id". You set it when creating a custom action. $CustomAction.Id = "MyCustomActionID".