# Hide button "Delete Item"

Tags: list, office-365, form, delete, item

I have a problem, because I want to accomplish a task before you delete an item from my list. For this I created a button "Delete client" that runs a workflow or run a javascript. But we have failed because the user can click the "Delete item" that is SharePoint, so I want to hide / block / remove the button "Delete item" of all forms.

[image]

BUT, I can not get permission to delete from the list because it will delete the item but executes code before deleting.

Comment: You can create an event receiver to perform some action before item is deleted.

Comment: Here is example similar to what you want to achieve. You may get some idea: http://blogs.sharepoint911.com/blogs/jennifer/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FOR ON-PREMISES**

You have to create a farm solution with [HideCustomAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms414790.aspx) element or you can event create you own custom action with your own implementation. Here is a [blog post](https://www.martinhatch.com/2008/10/hiding-menu-items-and-site-settings-in.html), or another [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225905/how-do-i-use-hidecustomaction-to-remove-the-site-contents-link-from-quick-laun) about hiding custom actions.

To use this method you have to know your location ID. They are documented in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537543(v=office.15).aspx).

To hide a delete button in List you should use

`Location = CommandUI.Ribbon`

`Control ID = Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.DeleteItem`

**FOR OFFICE 365**

You are using Office 365 environment so you cannot use farm solutions. In this case you should use CSOM (with PowerShell or JavaScript) to register a [UserCustomAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.usercustomactions.aspx) on your list. [Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146647/hide-new-document-command-from-ribbon-using-powershell) is sample how to do this with PowerShell (with JS it is very similar). In your case you have to use this `CommandUIExtention` property:

```
 <CommandUIExtension> 
     <CommandUIDefinitions> 
         <CommandUIDefinition Location='Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.DeleteItem' /> 
     </CommandUIDefinitions>
 </CommandUIExtension>"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: He is using Office 365. Creating a farm solution is not a good answer to the question.

Comment: Congratulations on your answer, I bet you contains certification in SharePoint as I am doing: p. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can add these lines of CSS using a content editor webpart to hide the delete button.

```
/* For Dispform.aspx */
a[id="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.DeleteItem-Medium"]
{
display:none;
}


/* For Editform.aspx */
a[id="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Actions.DeleteItem-Large"]
{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: His case works in special forms where I put this code. If you create new form or a private form this will not work and will need again to make the adjustment, and in the case of private form will not function. Congratulations on your help in cases of specific forms.

Comment: great CCS and works great but shame it has to be implemented on every form if wanting to hide the delete button :) yes there are permission rules but when you delete the EDIT option then the WF won't trigger as the edit right is required ..

Answer (score 2):

You can have a custom permission level without delete permission. Assign the users/groups of this list this new permission level.

Then in the workflow you can use the impersonation step to still allow your workflow to do the delete.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but as I mentioned I can not filter by permission because I'm making a script that does not use as another user or use key script creator. But your idea works in cases of workflows. Congratulations

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you're welcome. Just wanted to add that it is possible to use a script to trigger a workflow. So you can combine custom JS with the power of workflows.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Robert Lindgren's post I got mine working (for a custom edit infopath form - 2010) by using

```
/* For edit form:  Issue/editifs.aspx */
a[id="Ribbon.Tabs.InfoPathListTab.Actions.Controls.btnDelete-Large"]
{
display:none;
}
```

and

```
/* For view form: - Issue/displayifs.aspx  */
a[id="Ribbon.Tabs.InfoPathListDisplayTab.Manage.Controls.btnDelete-Medium"]
{
display:none;
}
```

It obviously depends on your SharePoint's template implementation. I had to look it up in the dev tools of the browser to see what the ID on the href for the delete button was.

I had to enable "Alternate CSS URL" in  "Site Master Page Settings" to have a CSS file I could use (to "Specify a CSS file to be used by this publishing site and all sites") as I don't have full access to the servers (only site collection administrator to my SharePoint site within the organisation).  I think I had to enable "SharePoint Server Publishing" in the "Manage site features" to get "Site Master Page Settings".